# json.encode() not returning anything in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

My code looks like this:

```
$hostname = 'myhost.com';
$database = 'heading';
$username = 'me';
$password = 'pw';
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * from mytable";
$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($result); //This works and dumps the array with the right data
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

This `echo`s nothing back though. No errors, just nothing. If I try `echo($result)` this echos "Array".

What's happening here?

Comment: echo is no good for outputting arrays. Use var_dump or print_r.

Comment: @CBroe echo should work as he is echoing a json string.

Comment: I can `print_r` my variable `$result`, but it's an array versus a JSON object.

Comment: @MarcB I know that. I think your message is suppose to be for CBroe

Comment: What happens if you remove header?

Comment: make sure that json itself didn't fail. e.g. `var_dump(json_encode(...));` would show a boolean false if the encoding failed, and then you'd check `json_last_error()` for the reason why. print_r won't show boolean falses - it'll just print them as an empty zero-length string. var_dump() would show `(bool)false`

Comment: @CodeGodie: No he’s not, he said `echo($result)` results in `Array`.

Comment: can you provide the result set you get when you `var_dump($result)` or `print_r($result)` ?

Comment: @MarcB I'm getting boolean false. `var_dump(json_last_error())` gives me int(5)...whatever that is.

Comment: Just to reinforce this, I tested locally and it didn't work either...

Comment: @FirstOne This actually worked until I did something to it, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: http://php.net/json_last_error  error code 5 should be malformed utf-8 character. you probably haven't enabled utf8 in your php->mysql connection, and one or more utf chars in the db data got corrupted coming over to php.

Comment: @MarcB That definitely could be it, as I just added stuff to the database. Where do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @MarcB I found one letter e with an accent on it in one entry. That was the problem. Thanks!